# Google Chart issues

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to use a Google chart but not hard code it. I am trying to populate the chart with a while loop. Here is my code:

```
var drinks = data.split("\n");
    var ii = 0;

    //create chart
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Beer');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Beers');
    var rows = drinks.length / 2;
    data.addRows(76);

    //iprints data
    while(  ii < drinks.length-1 ) {
        data.setValue( ii, drinks[ii], drinks[ii+1]  );

        ii = ii +2;
    }

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'Drinks',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
```

My data is coming from a text file that is formatted like this.

name
#
name 
#
name 
#

When I look in the chrome console I get this error when the code to make the chart is executed:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid column index drinks[ii]. Should be an integer
>   in the range [0-1].

Comment: and why does my post get voted down 1?

Answer (score 3):

According the [Google Visualizations API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_setValue), the second argument to data.setValue() should be a column index.  You've added two columns ('Beer' and 'Beers'), so you can only use 0 or 1.

I would try something like this:

```
var drinks = data.split("\n");
var ii = 0;

//create chart
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Beer');
data.addColumn('number', 'Beers');
var rows = drinks.length / 2;
data.addRows(76);

//iprints data
for ( ii = 0 ; ii < drinks.length - 1 ; ii++ ) {
    data.setValue( ii, 0, drinks[ii]);
}

// Set chart options
var options = {'title':'Drinks',
               'width':400,
               'height':300};

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

This will add a Beer name to the first column in each row.  I don't know what you want in the second column, but if you'd like to add some data there as well, you could include a second line in the for loop:

```
data.setValue( ii, 1, 'some other data');
```

One other note, however - you create a variable 'rows', but never use it.  I think it probably should go into the call to addRows() immediately below so that you base the number of rows on the number of names in your data.

---

**Edit**

In response to your question about why no data shows up - the bar chart sizes come from the second column (i.e. the number column) in your DataTable.  In the code above, I only populated the first column.  I now understand that every other line in your data contains an integer, so I've modified the code slightly.  You can try it out at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YB3bA/) (Also included below).

```
var beers = 'Budweiser\n50\nTsingdao\n10\nSam Adams\n15';
var drinks = beers.split("\n");

// Create the data table.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Beer');
data.addColumn('number', 'Beers');
data.addRows(drinks.length / 2);

// Set chart options
var options = {'title':'Drinks',
               'width':400,
               'height':300};

//iprints data
for ( var i = 0 ; i < drinks.length - 1 ; i += 2 ) {
    data.setValue(i/2, 0, drinks[i]);
    data.setValue(i/2, 1, parseInt((drinks[i+1])));
}

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: from what I understood is that where you put the 0. Should be the beer name, then the next value is the number of that beer.

Comment: making the first change you said does display a chart but does not put anything in it

Comment: If you run this html code you can see visually what I am trying to produce just with different values:

http://pastebin.com/tC7AGK3i

Comment: Hi @Mike, I've edited my answer to be a bit more clear and link to a running version of the javascript code.

Comment: hmmm, I tried what you did and I got this error in the console:

Uncaught Error: Invalid value for numOrArray: 42.5. If numOrArray is a number it should be a nonnegative integer.

Comment: While trying to debug, I also noticed if in the data.addrows() if I hard coded 75 (the numbers of beers I get back for a certain query) it works other then formatting being sloppy. Still not sure why the drinks.length/2 doesn't work.

Comment: It sounds like drinks.length is an odd number, so drinks.length/2 ends with .5.  I think you should double check the format of your data string and either make sure it's stable or add some code to handle cases when the length is odd.